# Google Sheets Scripts - setUnderline not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, underline

I want to make a new text format to a specific cell....A1 in the sheet "Frachtbrief".
For the size setFontSize and the Alignment it works very well.
But not for the Underline function. I used several writings such as .....nothing works. I always get, that it is not a function....but the syntax is working for the other text formating styles. It is also described herE: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#setunderlineunderline

```
  var schreiben7 = sheet3.getRange("A1");
  schreiben7.setValue("Frachtbrief");

  var set=schreiben7.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  var set=schreiben7.setFontSize("14");
  var set=schreiben7.setUnderline("true");
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

The [setUnderline()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#setunderlineunderline) method you link to is a Slides method. In Sheets, you should use [setFontLine()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setfontlinefontline), like this:

```
  const set = schreiben7
    .setHorizontalAlignment('center')
    .setFontSize(14)
    .setFontLine('underline');
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Underline richText

```
function underlineRichText() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const l = sh.getRange(1,1).getDisplayValue();
  const ul = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setUnderline(true).build();
  const v = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(l).setTextStyle(0,l.length,ul).build();
  sh.getRange(1,1).setRichTextValue(v);
}
```

Demo:

[image]